# react material table nested json

Tags: reactjs, material-table

using https://material-table.com to display data in table, i need help with nested json. i'm not able to display nested data

json:

```
{
"Name_test0": [
    {
        "_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "Name_test1": "XXXX",
        "Name_test2": [
            {
                "Name_test3": "xxxx"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

```
       <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: "Name_test1", field: "Name_test1" }
            { title: "Name_test3", field: "Name_test2.Name_test3" },
          ]}
          data={state.gettingData}
          title="List"
          options={{
            filtering: true,
          }}
        />
```

i got solution:

```
    {
  title: "test",
  field: "Name_test2",
  render: (rowData) => {
    return <div>{rowData.Name_test2[0].Name_test3}</div>;
  },
}
```

Comment: i got solution:

Comment: Can you post the answer? I have a similar use case